# How to make SlickEdit's search results look like Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, grep

I use "find in files" (grep) and the search results very often for navigating code. Currently I use both SlickEdit and Notepad++ at different times. Both applications do this "find in files" but Notepad++ has a much better search results screen. The results are saved even after a new search is kicked off. In SlickEdit, it seems that new searches clear the results from the previous search. I know I can tick the Search Results window options "New" and "Auto-increment", but it seems choosing "New" does not persist to a new search (new search will return results on whatever tab you had open), and "Auto Increment" wraps around your tabs, it won't create a new tab for a new search.

What I really want is either "New" to be permanently selected. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found an answer just a few minutes after posting. It is the "append to output" checkbox that does what I want. It is more like notepad++ than what I described (but in descending order) regarding new tabs.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little bit to add value to future visitors with the same question? Where can I find this "append to output" checkbox?